# C Number Byte representation

Tags: c, byte, biginteger, gmp, sign

I have an `unsigned char vector mynumber[]` that represents a bigint.
This number is positive and I want to convert it in a negative number.

I have tried in this way

```
for(int i = 0; i < dimvector;i++)
 mynumber[i] = ~mynumber[i];
```

I iterate my vector but I need to sum one.
How sum one?

If I have a overflow, how to solve?

I work with GMP and after the export I must pass the vector to SHA256.

At the end I trasform the result of digest in a Big number using import (GMP).

In the import I have the same problem of the export.
The sign is important.

Comment: Your code doesn't actually do anything, as you are discarding the result of the `~mynumber[i]` expression.

Comment: i write bad but the problem is another.

Comment: it's always better to copy and paste actual code rather than typing in an approximation.

Answer (score 2):

Crikey. Ok, first up, how bignums are implemented: in GMP and in other libraries, typically you designate a fixed-width field as a "limb", or part of the number. You've got that part right so far, except that you're more likely to use `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` for 32 and 64-bit platforms respectively because these are the size of the registers and instructions like `adc` set a carry flag if adding two registers overflows.

Anyway, the point being, these limbs represent the actual magnitude of the bignum, not its sign. Using two's complement, we'd expect a sign bit somewhere, but that gets messy if you want to resize a number (and `adc` doesn't care about signing, it just does binary addition) since you need to find the old sign bit, extract it, remember it, and it back in in the right place... very slow.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve inverting the bits in each limb. If you imagine a set of limbs like this (short for simplicity)

```
1011 0111 1010 1011 = 47019
```

You'd end up with:

```
0100 1000 0101 0100 = 18516
```

Anyway, GMP doesn't represent sign in the limbs. The signed integer type in GMP is `mpz_t` which is defined by this struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    int _mp_alloc;        /* Number of *limbs* allocated and pointed
                             to by the _mp_d field.  */
    int _mp_size;         /* abs(_mp_size) is the number of limbs the
                             last field points to.  If _mp_size is
                             negative this is a negative number.  */
    mp_limb_t *_mp_d;     /* Pointer to the limbs.  */
} __mpz_struct;
typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];
```

So as you can see, `_mp_size` is how GMP represents signed numbers.

In code (specifically, `mpz/aors.h`) you'll see this used:

```
usize = u->_mp_size;
vsize = VARIATION v->_mp_size;

// .....

if ((usize ^ vsize) < 0)
{
  /* U and V have different sign.  Need to compare them to determine
 which operand to subtract from which.  */

  // does subtraction instead of add.
```

The actual operations are performed by the `mpn_` series of functions which are your unsigned types.

GMP has a number of import/export functions from basic types which should allow you to set the size correctly. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but assuming they're insufficient, you ought to be able to set it yourself.